# Is there a feature in Java to make sure that method is called

Tags: java, builder

I'm using a pattern similar to builder/fluid API to configure some timing service. I'm aware that it's not a typical builder, but it looks very nice and I want to keep this style.

It looks like:

```
Action someAction = getAction();
someAction.shouldRunEvery(5).seconds();
```

Where last verb can be seconds(), minutes(), milliseconds() etc.
The code in last method in chain actually writes the change to repository.
Typical error(and I've made it more than once despite knowing the internals) is using a method like this:

```
someAction.shouldRunEvery(10);
```

Is there a way to ensure that function of an interface is called on object?
I can use any feature of java 8/9 and/or additional libraries.

Addition 1:
How fluid API is produced:

```
interface Action{ ActionUnit shouldRunEvery (int time);}
interface ActionUnit { void seconds(); void minutes(); ... etc.}
```

Addition 2:
I've tried to look into exceptions, but can't figure how to stitch them on it and keep things tidy.

Addition 3:
Possibly the best answer is to change API to something like this:

```
someAction.shouldRunEvery(seconds(5));
```

but in this case I'm losing fluidity.

Comment: This question might actually be better suited for softwareengineering SE.  Can we have a mod move it?

Comment: do you consider changing `shouldRunEvery` signature to work somehow like this: `shouldRunEvery(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)`?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot force a method to be called in Java. You can only know you have ended properly when the return type is the one you expect. This said, better to let `shouldRunEvery()` return something like an `ActionBuilder` and `seconds()` return the `Action`. That is how builders do it.

Comment: There are ways of getting around it, such as making seconds the default unit, and calling it with `.minutes()` simply serves to change the default unit, allowing you to skip the unit and just call `shouldRunEvery(5)`.  If you document your library, there should be no issues.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim I'm not exactly understand your suggestion, can you, please, explain it?

Comment: As an author of the russian article described in the answers above I'd like to clarify something.
It's not the original, it's based on this publication: [Java Generics are Turing Complete](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05274.pdf). The publication is in english so you can actually read it and understand what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no good way do it in Java, but it is still possible. You can find "safe builder" sample here [Generator of Turing Machines that run on Java generic types](https://github.com/ibessonov/tm). 
This sample uses the fact that Java generics are turing complete. You can read original article (russian only [Тьюринг-полнота Generic типов Java](https://habrahabr.ru/post/330724/))

But I am afraid it is too terrible syntax for real life.

Comment: @Anton Why? That answer is <? super <? super <? super <? super :D

Answer (score 2):

You could enforce the call to one of the time unit methods by having them return an Action, and having `getAction()` return not an Action, but a nascent object (e.g. a 'PreAction'):

```
PreAction someAction = getPreAction();
```

The interfaces would thus look like this:

```
interface PreAction{ ActionUnit shouldRunEvery (int time);}
interface ActionUnit { Action seconds(); Action minutes(); ... etc.}
```

Now, when you forget about the time unit, you end up with a PreAction object which cannot serve as an Action.